# How to check whether SharePoint web server to app server communication is going over oauth http or https secure channel?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, oauth

We have SharePoint 2013 on premises farm  and have SSl enabled for web application.

Is the server to server trust configured with OAuth framework with default https as my web application is running with SSL?

How is the default communication channel between web server and application server in the farm ?

How can I get this SSL handshake information if it secure channel?

Answer (score 0):

By default, communication between SharePoint servers and service applications within a farm takes place by using HTTP with a binding to TCP 32843. When you publish a service application, you can select either HTTP or HTTPS with the following bindings:

- HTTP binding: TCP 32843
- HTTPS binding: TCP 32844

You can change the protocol and port binding for each service application. On the Service Applications page in Central Administration, select the service application, and then click Publish.

Reference: [Plan security hardening for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/security-hardening)

This answer is semi-valid, as it only obfuscates HTTP-traffic to another TCP-port instead of disabling it. No documentation or practical experience exists on the question `how to disable HTTP for SharePoint service-communication?`.

My idea: You could route the inter-farm-traffic to a separate pair of NICs and encapsulate them to a `inter-farm-VLAN` on your network. This won't be a simple approach, as the number of internal and external WebService-calls in SharePoint is huge.

Comment: thanks a lot for your clear and detailed response